# Making macro expanded when Debug GNU assembly program using GDB

Tags: debugging, gcc, gdb, gnu, gnu-assembler

I write a program using assembly language and compile it by `GCC` as following:

```
gcc -g sha256-avx.S main256.c -o test.exe
```

Now, I need to debug it. But I don't know how to the content of macro. The following is my method about using `GDB`.

```
(gdb) s
400     vmovdqa XFER, _XFER(%rsp)
(gdb) s
401     FOUR_ROUNDS_AND_SCHED
(gdb) s
403     vpaddd  1*16(TBL), X0, XFER
(gdb) s
404     vmovdqa XFER, _XFER(%rsp)
(gdb) s
405     FOUR_ROUNDS_AND_SCHED
```

`FOUR_ROUNDS_AND_SCHED` is a macro defined by myself.

```
.macro FOUR_ROUNDS_AND_SCHED
 ## compute s0 four at a time and s1 two at a time
 ## compute W[-16] + W[-7] 4 at a time

 mov     e, y0          # y0 = e
 MY_ROR  (25-11), y0             # y0 = e >> (25-11)
 mov     a, y1                   # y1 = a
 vpalignr $4, X2, X3, XTMP0      # XTMP0 = W[-7]
 MY_ROR  (22-13), y1             # y1 = a >> (22-13)
 xor     e, y0                   # y0 = e ^ (e >> (25-11))
 mov     f, y2                   # y2 = f
 MY_ROR  (11-6), y0              # y0 = (e >> (11-6)) ^ (e >> (25-6))
 xor     a, y1                   # y1 = a ^ (a >> (22-13)

 // ...
.endm
```

In fact, `My_ROR` is also a macro defined in my program.

I want to watch the every instruction in macro(`FOUR_ROUNDS_AND_SCHED` and `My_ROR`) when debug program step-by-step using GDB. How should I compile my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I compile my program?

You can compile the program as you do now, but use `x/4i $pc` to see actual instructions, and `stepi` to single step instructions instead of lines.

Comment: ```x/4i $pc``` instruction make me see some instructions that will be executed. But it isn't that I hope.

Comment: I hope ```step-by-step``` to see each instructions that are executed currently.

Comment: Hope you give me a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try combining `disp/i $pc` with `stepi`?